# How does forEach actually work on a NodeList

Tags: javascript

Very aware of the method:

```
[].prototype.forEach.call(aNodeList, function(node){
     // manipulate node
});
```

So, inside the `forEach` method, `this` will point to an array (which, in this case would be a NodeList). So you can use Array methods on the array-like NodeList.

I get this, but what I'm a little confused about is how this actually works? ie. why can't I do `aNodeList.forEach()` but I can call `forEach` on the Array prototype and it work? How can array methods work on an array-like object?

This question may not actually have an objective answer, just very curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native implemenation of `forEach` is something like this (this is greatly simplified, though):

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(f) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        f(this[i]);
    };
};
```

But, `NodeList`s can be looped through the same way! So if you call `Array`'s `forEach` on a `NodeList`, it will behave the same way.

In fact, I could even create my own array-like object, and use `Array`'s `forEach` on it!

```
> Array.prototype.forEach.call({length: 3, '0': 'zero', '1': 'one', '2': 'two'}, function(x){ console.log(x); });
zero
one
two
```

As to why there's no `forEach` on `NodeList`s, it's because [it doesn't extend `Array`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can%27t_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F).

So why doesn't `NodeList` just have its own `forEach` implementation? Well, the answer basically boils down to "Because the people who made the JavaScript implementations didn't make one."

Comment: Loved the explanation.